# Rename Monodroid files in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

I am using Mono for Android and Visual Studio 2012. I have noticed that if I create a new file and forget to name it on create, so then I right-click and then rename the file, the Resource Designer does not notice any changes (I can't find any id's I have created). However, if when I create a new file I give it a proper name from the beginning, Resource Designer does know changes.

In fact, it seems that renaming the file actually creates a new file, and the ResourceDesigner is still looking at the original file.

How do you rename a file in Visual Studio and Mono for Android so the Resource Designer knows to look at it?

Comment: Did you try to build/rebuild the solution after the changes? I think resource designer will update the changes correctly after doing so.

Comment: I tried that several times to no avail. If the file had been renamed, it would not include any changes. The rebuild would be successful, but I couldn't access any IDs or thing inside it (ResourceDesigner didn't update). Interestingly, if I renamed it back to the original file, it would start working again. Also interestingly, it would recognize the layout file (it didn't throw an error when I use it for SetContentView) but nothing inside it?

Comment: I think the best bet is to report this to bugzilla.xamarin.com - they'll look at the issue and hopefully address it

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working in the current Stable version of Xamarin.Android (4.8.01013). However, in my dealings with adding files and renaming, sometimes the IDE "loses" what the files BuildAction should be.

To double-check:

> right-click the file -> Properties -> BuildAction

If expected to be in the Resource.Designer, set the action to "AndroidResource"